# How to .subscribe to setInterval() in Angular app?

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, cordova, ionic-framework

I am trying to build an iOS location tracking app with the Ionic 5 Framework, Angular, and Cordova Geolocation Plugin.

I used to get user location changes with the watchPosition() function and it worked fine on Android devices. However, it does not work on iOS devices.

My new approach is to get the current location with the getCurrentPosition() function combined with setInterval(). To get an updated location every one or two seconds.

Unfortunately, I am getting following error now:

***TypeError: this.watchLocationUpdates.subscribe is not a function***

Anyone an Idea how to fix this?

````
  watchLocation() {
    const options = {
      maximumAge: 3600000,
      timeout: 5000,
      enableHighAccuracy: true,
    };
    this.isWatching = true;
    this.trackingId =  '-' + Math.random().toString(36).substr(2, 28);

    // Please find relevant setInterval() part below
    this.watchLocationUpdates = setInterval(() => { this.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(options); }, 1000);
    this.watchLocationUpdatesSub = this.watchLocationUpdates.subscribe((resp) => {
      this.geoLocations = resp.coords;
      this.geoLatitude = resp.coords.latitude;
      this.geoLongitude = resp.coords.longitude;
      this.geoAccuracy = Math.trunc(resp.coords.accuracy);
      this.timeStamp = resp.timestamp;

      const position = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
      this.map.setCenter(position);
      this.map.setZoom(16);

      this.markers.map(marker => marker.setMap(null));
      this.markers = [];
        const latLng = new google.maps.LatLng(resp.coords.latitude, resp.coords.longitude);
        const marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          map: this.map,
          icon: {
            path: google.maps.SymbolPath.CIRCLE,
            scale: 13,
            fillColor: '#1AA0EC',
            fillOpacity: 1,
            strokeColor: 'white',
            strokeWeight: 2
        },
          position: latLng
        });
        this.markers.push(marker);

      console.table('watchLocation function called', {
        trackingId: this.trackingId,
        latitude: this.geoLatitude,
        longitude: this.geoLongitude,
        accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
        timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
        uId: this.uId
        });
      this.geolocationService.insertUserGeolocation({
        trackingId: this.trackingId,
        latitude: this.geoLatitude,
        longitude: this.geoLongitude,
        accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
        timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
        uId: this.uId
        })
        .subscribe((response) => {
          localStorage.setItem('lastLocation', JSON.stringify({
            trackingId: this.trackingId,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude,
            accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
            timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
            uId: this.uId
            }));
          console.log(`user location data inserted in FB`, {
            trackingId: this.trackingId,
            latitude: this.geoLatitude,
            longitude: this.geoLongitude,
            accuracy: this.geoAccuracy,
            timeStamp: this.timeStamp,
            uId: this.uId
            });
        });
      });
  }```
````

Comment: [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/setInterval) doesn't return an Observable, or a Promise for that matter. It returns an interval ID which uniquely identifies the interval. You cannot subscribe to it.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Im not an experienced coder. Do you know how tho fix it?

Comment: [`interval`](https://rxjs-dev.firebaseapp.com/api/index/function/interval) is the Observable alternative to `setInterval()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [`interval()` from RxJS](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/interval.html):

```
// RxJS v6+
import { interval } from 'rxjs';

const source = interval(1000);

source.subscribe(/* your logic here */);
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. Unfortunately, I cant find a way to implement it in my existing logic. Do you know how to solve it?